# Call multiple async functions within a single app response - Express

Tags: javascript, api, express

What's the correct way to call multiple **async** functions and send their response in express ?
I tried to use **try / catch**, **await**, but nothing works. This is my problem :
When I do this

```
app.get('/api/caristes/reappro', async (req, res) => {
        const a = await a()
        const b= await b()

        res.send({reappro: a, caristes: b})
})
```

The data **b** send by the server is not correct. But I tested the function **b** again and again and it's working perfectly. Then, I made request to my API and I found values are different than expected, so I deduced my problem is from my server request. The data of function **b** seems to not be updated every time the server is called.

For the other links, I send data like this :

```
a().then(result=> {
    res.send(result)
})
```

and it's working perfectly. But I didn't manage to use multiple **.then** with multiple async functions : it returns an error (undefined value).
Any suggestions ?

### EDIT : the two functions

function i named b :

```
const {alleesCircuit} = require('./alleesCircuit')
const {caristes} = require('./caristes');
const {lstMvtCariste} = require('./lstMvtCariste')

async function caristesAlleesHeure () {
    const caristesActifs = await caristes()
    const alleesCircuits = await alleesCircuit()
    const dernierMvt = await lstMvtCariste()
    
    for (let i in caristesActifs) {
        let tmp = []
        for (let j in caristesActifs[i].CIRCUITS) {
            for (let k in alleesCircuits) {
                if (Object.values(alleesCircuits[k]).includes(caristesActifs[i].CIRCUITS[j].toString())) {
                    tmp = [...tmp, ...alleesCircuits[k].ALLPIC]
                }
            }
        }
        const alleesCariste = [...new Set(tmp)]
        caristesActifs[i].ALLEES = alleesCariste
    }

    for (let i in caristesActifs) {
        // Tri par ordre croissant des allées attribuées aux caristes
        caristesActifs[i].ALLEES.sort(function(a,b) {
            return a - b
        })

        // Add zeros to have 21 values
        for (let j = 0; j <= 20; j++) {
            if(caristesActifs[i].ALLEES[j] !== j+1) {
                (caristesActifs[i].ALLEES).splice(j, 0, 0)
            }
        }

        // Replace all values !== 0 by 1
        for (k in caristesActifs[i].ALLEES) {
            if(caristesActifs[i].ALLEES[k] !== 0) {
                caristesActifs[i].ALLEES[k] = 1
            }
        }
    }
    
    let caristesAlleesHeure = []

    for(let i = 0; i < caristesActifs.length; i++) {
        caristesAlleesHeure.push({
            ...caristesActifs[i],
            ...(dernierMvt.find((codeUser) => codeUser.CODUTI === caristesActifs[i].CODCAR))
        })
    }

    return caristesAlleesHeure
}   

exports.caristesAlleesHeure = caristesAlleesHeure
```

We don't care about the **function a** because the server returns correct values of it

Comment: Can you provide the context of functions `a()` and `b()`?

Comment: What do you mean by context ? They are very long and specific functions but they both return an array of objects. I tested it multiple times at the same time when requesting the server, the functions were giving good results while the server didn't.

Comment: I mean include them in the question so we know what they do/return. If they are really long try to reduce them in a way we can still make some sense out of them.

Comment: Ok I'm doing it rn.

Comment: What is "incorrect" about the response from `b`? Are you sure function a doesn't matter? You said that if you didn't call `a` then `b` gave the correct results. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] (emphasis on the minimal).

Comment: I mean, after many test I saw that the problem comes from the async functions call, so I'm juste searching the correct way to call the two functions, wait for their results and then send back the two results. I know that the two functions work independantly.